# How to move funds around using foundry in forked mainnet?

Tags: foundry, forge

In mainnet forking, I am trying to move some fund, say from one LP token contract to address I control so that I can test functionality. Is there any cheatcode that enables me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For hardhat, there is an RPC method [Impersonating accounts](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks#impersonating-accounts) that allows you to do this. and it seems like Foundry [implemented something similar](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/pull/1912) as `anvil_impersonateAccount`.